# Confusion regarding "go" and "ko" in hiragana

Tags: hiragana

I am learning hiragana and the word *ichigo* has confused me. What is the hiragana for *go*? My hiragana chart has a symbol for *ko* but not *go*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The hiragana for *go* is `ご` — こ with [dakuten](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dakuten) (voicing mark). A larger hiragana chart should also include voiced hiragana (が: *ga*, ぼ: *bo*, etc), but the rule is fairly simple anyway.

See: [Ko (kana)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ko_(kana))